# selecting last row for every id in Laravel's Eloquent

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a history of every rental of a book from the library and based on that I want to show current status of ALL BOOKS in the library. If I have only id, book_id, status (bool), and timestamps how should I do it in the easiest way without touching SQL? I want to have the freshest record for every book_id for example:

```
|--|-------|------|----------|
|id|book_id|status|timestamp-|
|--|-------|------|----------|
| 1|      1|     0|12.12.2019|
| 2|      2|     0|13.12.2019|
| 3|      3|     0|14.12.2019|
| 4|      2|     1|15.12.2019|
| 5|      3|     1|16.12.2019|
| 6|      3|     0|17.12.2019|
|--|-------|------|----------|
```

and I want to get this:

```
|--|-------|------|----------|
|id|book_id|status|timestamp-|
|--|-------|------|----------|
| 1|      1|     0|12.12.2019|
| 4|      2|     1|15.12.2019|
| 6|      3|     0|17.12.2019|
|--|-------|------|----------|
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```php
$lastestBookRentHistory = YourBookRentHistoryModel::where('book_id', 123)->latest();
```

Note: `latest()` works only if you have `created_at` column on your table.
This is how `latest()` is defined.

```php
public function latest($column = 'created_at')
{
    return $this->orderBy($column, 'desc');
}
```

If your timestamp column is not named as `created_at`, use lastest('your-column-name') instead.

Comment: ok, but what if I want to get an entry for every id? Assuming that every book was rented multiple times

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/blog-contest-may-mayhem/issues/15 :D try this one.